# How to tell user which character, one had sketch Using Gesture?

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am making an application.In which i let user to make any gesture.Now i want to compare this gesture with English like `A, B` etc.

Suppose he make Gesture like A then i have to show that you have type A letter.Give some idea about it.Any code example or link most welcome.

**Edited**

And if user is not able to draw a complete Letter with one gesture then i want to combine two gesture.

**Edited**

Please do not give me link for how to make a simple gesture application

Comment: not ocr.its completely different.If you user make any gesture then i want to tell him what you have typed?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following links:

http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/

and this

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

Comment: Thank you for your response..but these link tell only about how to create simple gesture.I have already went through all.And i have created one gesture application that combine with surfaceview.